# How to get rid of ValueError: could not convert string to float 'Enrolled' in Google Colab?

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

I keep on getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Enrolled'

I was given a dataset and was asked to perform 5 machine algorithms. As per my previous question, only 2 of them successfully worked. (Thank you for the help!)

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
random_forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,random_state=0)
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
try:
  Y_prediction = random_forest.predict(X_test)
  random_forest.score(X_train, y_train)
  acc_random_forest = round(random_forest.score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)
  print(acc_random_forest)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: I am using the pandas, numpy, seaborn, matplotlib and sklearn libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error states that you are trying to cast the string `"Enrolled"` to a float. Here's a reproduction:

```py
>>> float("Enrolled")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Enrolled'
```

I do not know the lib you're using but the doc for `predict()` says

> Parameters:
> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
> The input samples. **Internally, its dtype will be converted to dtype=np.float32**. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted into a sparse csr_matrix.

Emphasis mine

So, given the fact that you seem to be working with train-related data, and that this functions tries to cast stuff to float, and the string being *Enrolled* I guess you sort of passed a table header string with your data to your model or something like that?